# Not able to load kibana dashboard from fetch api

Tags: javascript, elasticsearch, nginx, kibana

I have kibana configured with nginx reverse proxy ,now what I want is display the kibana reports in iframe .

The problem is my kibana dashboard is protected by nginx basic auth (which asks for username and password while loading).

I by passed the security with fetch api and loaded the incoming response in the iframe see code

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>



<div id="content">
    <div style="height:800px;">
        <iframe id="output-frame-id" src="" scrolling="no"
            frameborder="0" height="100%" width="100%" ></iframe>
    </div>
</div>


<script>

let URL="http://localhost:5601"
async function make()
{
    const response = await fetch(URL, {
        method: 'get',
        headers: {
          'Authorization': 'Basic ' + btoa("username" + ":" + "password"),
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',

        },

      });
      const posts = await response.blob();

      console.log(posts);
var myURL = window.URL || window.webkitURL

var data_url=myURL.createObjectURL(posts)

      document.querySelector('#output-frame-id').src = data_url;


}
make();

</script>



</body>


</html>
```

I am able to get the data but it only shows loading page of kibana.Rest dashboard is not loaded. Any idea how to solve this issue ?

Comment: Why do you want to put Kibana in Iframe? Why not just using it directly ?

Comment: The kibana url will have dynamic query parameters ,that is used to generate dashboards according to the data passed

Comment: FYI `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header should be set on the server side, not in the fetch api

Comment: Thanks for the information ,Its already set in server :)

Comment: were you able to solve this issue? @trinity